# How to continue reading a Google+ community/collection?

Tags: google-plus

I'm reading a Google+ community. Now I want to quit and come back later on that page, but I want to navigate to the position of the post I have read before I leave, but I don't know how.

Currently I scroll and scroll until I reach the post, or repeat press End key, which may take long time. I know how to bookmark the post, what I ask is continue read the community from a specific post. I want to know if there is other way to do it faster?